# Freemarker оператор if

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

Столкнулся с проблемой, что при сравнении переменной с числом всё крашится и вылетает туча ошибок. Без блока if всё высвечивается корректно, но мне нужно сравнение по этой переменной.

```html
<#if subjectSelectForForumInfo.formId == 1>
                    <#list subjectSelectForForum as subjectSelectForForumInfo>
                    <div class="rdel-apl-content">


                        <div class="link-rdel-content">


                            <div class="descrip-link-rdel"><a href="">${subjectSelectForForumInfo.zagolovok}</a></div>

                            <div class="information-descrip">
                                <div class="info-tem-count">
                                    <div class="content-centre">${subjectSelectForForumInfo.messages_count}</div>
                                    <div class="content-centre">Сообщений</div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="info-mes-count">
                                    <div class="content-centre">${subjectSelectForForumInfo.views_count}</div>
                                    <div class="content-centre">Просмотров</div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="author-descrip">
                                    <div class="content-centre">#${subjectSelectForForumInfo.user.username}</div>
                                    <div class="content-centre">Создатель темы</div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="strin-white"> </div>
                    </div>
                    </#list>
                     </#if>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверял оператором `if` коллекцию, что вводило в ступор весь код. Оператор `if` поместил внутри коллекции, чтобы он бежал по коллекции.

```
<#list subjectSelectForForum as subjectSelectForForumInfo>
       <#if subjectSelectForForumInfo.formId == 1>

              <-- Код -->
 
        </#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Сглупил и поставил if до листа :) пофиксил

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]